# Android Studio Room and DAO: Making a query with where 'field=condition' argument

Tags: android, android-room, dao

In Android Studio DAO interface, this code:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StrategyLinks WHERE Id_Property=:condition")
    long countStrategyLinks(String condition);
```

Works fine when I call:

```
MyDao.countStrategyLinks("10");
```

BUT, I really want a more generic form, like this:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StrategyLinks WHERE :condition")
    long countStrategyLinks(String condition);
```

When I call:

```
MyDao.countStrategyLinks("Id_Property=10");
```

What DON'T WORK at all.
There are some way to overcome this limitations? Also, is possible to pass the table name (StrategyLinks in this example) as a argument? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `RawQuery` like this:

```kotlin
 @Dao
 interface RawDao {
   @RawQuery
   long countStrategyLinks(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
 }

 // Usage of RawDao
 SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(
     "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StrategyLinks WHERE ?",
     new Object[]{ condition});
 long result = rawDao.countStrategyLinks(query);
```

you can find better details in [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery)

Comment: Thanks! Hope that someday DAO incorporate this capacity in some way that all queries codes stay in DAO itself.

Comment: @sgm yeah I hope that too, it's prettier like that.